# zsh completion: Do not strip quotes?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

When using completion inside a double quoted string, zsh strips the leading `"`. E.g. 
`export PATH="$HOME/software<TAB>` 
becomes 
`export PATH=$HOME/software` 
How can I convince zsh that I like the leading double quote  and keep it?

Comment: For me, that does not happen if there is no parameter inside the double quotes. Default behaviour seems to be to replace parameters by their value and remove double quotes in favour of quoting by "\" : `"foo $HOME bar<TAB>` → `foo\ /home/adaephon\ bar`. If there are no parameters, the double quotes remain: `"/home/ad<TAB>` → `"/home/adaephon`

Comment: @Adaephon: You are right, this behavior only occurs when environment variables are referenced inside the started quoted string.  You can disable the expansion of environment variables by setting  zstyle accordingly:  
`zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _ignored`  
i.e. without the `_expand` keyword.